# How can I unit test methods that have object as parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm refactoring some code and would like to junit test some methods but they are using objects that are created by the underlying framework. If I am unable to re-create these objects myself  does this mean I cannot write unit tests on methods that take as an argument the framework generated object ?

So for example a jetspeed Page object

Comment: What is the "underlying framework" here? Why can't you recreate these objects? It's all a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: Can't create those objects? The framework doesn't provide reasonably-testable versions, or...? They're not mockable?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to get a hold of these "underlying framework" objects one way or another - either by extending those objects to roll your own (if there's an issue because all of their constructors are protected), or by keeping an instance of the framework running inside your JUnit tests if all of the framework objects' constructors are private.  If they are package-private, you could just have your JUnit test package hierarchy mimic that of the framework.

Comment: @DaveNewton no, it doesn't seem to be easily mockable

Comment: @user470184 I don't understand that statement--how have you tried mocking those objects? In any case, without knowing more about what you're trying to test, it's really difficult to provide constructive advice.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've tried by reading the api docs for jetspeed and it seems non trivial, was hoping for a framework that could simplify the task

Comment: And there are many mocking frameworks, so you're in luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)?

Comment: Or PowerMock if the classes are final

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a good idea to wrap objects that you dont have control over in wrapperclasses. Inject the interface of the wrapper. You could create a PageWrapper:IPageWrapper class that encapsulates the functionality that you need.